# Action<Span<byte>> throws compilation error, but delegate void TestMeDelegate(Span<byte> data) doesn't

Tags: c#, system.memory

Examine the following code.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void TestMeDelegate(Span<byte> data);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMeDelegate testMeDelegate = TestMe;
        Action<Span<byte>> testMeAction = TestMe;
    }

    static void TestMe(Span<byte> data)
    {
    }
}
```

The row using testMeDelegate works, but the row using testMeAction
throws

> The type '`Span<byte>`' may not be used as a type argument

I am targeting.net 4.7.2 with the System.Memory nuget version 4.5.1

Langversion is set to C# latest minor version (latest) should be 7.3

Questions:

Is this simply a compiler bug?

What are the differences between Action and delegate in this scenario?

Comment: Maybe wrong compiler/.NET version that does not yet understand the new `Span` class?

Comment: @UweKeim If that were true, wouldn't the delegate fail? (Honest question. I've been known to be spectacularly dumb in the past, and there's no evidence to support the claim that this has changed.)

Comment: The restriction against using stack-only types as type arguments applies globally.  For regular generic types, it makes sense, because the compiler has no way to enfore stack-only semantics (there is no `ref` generic constraint AFAIK).  I suppose they could have made an exception for delegates, but it seems they did not.  Regardless, it’s by design, so not a bug.

Comment: Try `delegate void TestMeDelegate<T>(T data);` instead.  That would be the equivalent of `Action<T>`.

Comment: I just checked, I can execute the delegate without throwing runtime exceptions.

Comment: Same as [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330950/actionspant-throws-compilation-error-but-delegate-void-testmedelegatespan).  Span<> is a ref struct that does not permit boxing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's exactly as the error describes.

The `Span<T>` type is a [`ref struct`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2018/03/02/c-7-series-part-9-ref-structs/), meaning it's storage location can only be on the stack (So not on the heap). The compiler will output diagnostics for cases were this can't be guaranteed.

The problem is that the compiler can't determine this with generics. Although there are some situations that the compiler could detect (like yours), the compiler team has decided not to allow `ref struct` types to be used as generic types at all.

I don't know the exact reasoning why they don't properly check this for generic types, but some I can imagine are:

- Would increase complexity of the compiler by too much
- It'll be very difficult, if possible at all, to generate proper diagnostic messages for cases where a type can not be used as generic parameter for a given type.

Comment: Here's the [microsoft documentation for `ref structs` and reference semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/reference-semantics-with-value-types#ref-struct-type)

Comment: I also thought, it should be possible to check, but the reasoning that the generics check is too complicated satisfies me for an answer.